# .NET Metadata ValidationAttribute html encoding bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've just noticed the following rendering error when using Metadata.
I've played with all the rendering culture etc. everywhere inside the project but I can't make it working.
Would someone have a clue? Thanks in advance for your help !

**Rendering bug :**

[image: Link to screenshot bug]

The accent is well rendered in the validation summary but not inside the tooltip (*).
**The html code is displayed instead of the accent character itself.**

This should be a common mistake but none of the ValidationAttribute posts helped me... The only possible solution that I think of would be to use custom validation attribute but I guess the solution is much simpler than that.

Note that it's working well without metadata (textbox+RequiredFieldValidator).

**Page code :**

```
<EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DynamicControl ID="tbnumEdit" runat="server" DataField="num" Mode="Edit" ValidationGroup="Edit" />
                        <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Ok" ValidationGroup="Edit" />
                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Annuler" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Edit" />
                        </span>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
```

**Metadata :**

```
public class plaqueMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "La plaque ne peut pas être vide.")]
    public String num { get; set; }
}
```

Settings from Web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="fr-BE" culture="fr-BE" />
```

Comment: If anybody has a clue to ask better the question/problem, please do not hesitate ;)